# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'expect' at node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:1

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, karma-mocha

I created a React app using `create-react-app` and i want to run some tests for my components.  When i run `npm test` i get the following error message:

```
> karma start


START:
07 12 2017 16:18:37.676:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at 
http://0.0.0.0:9876/
07 12 2017 16:18:37.679:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with 
unlimited concurrency
07 12 2017 16:18:37.690:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 12 2017 16:18:38.862:INFO [Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected 
on socket 9zYM4BbuqSydz
_toAAAA with id 71036615
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at testFiles/CountDownClock.test.js:1

Finished in 0.154 secs / 0 secs @ 16:18:39 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

SUMMARY:
√ 0 tests completed
Chrome 62.0.3202 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'expect'
at node_modules/mocha/mocha.js:1

x Error while running the tests! Exit code: 1

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "timer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "karma start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^21.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2"
  }
}
```

here is my test file:  CountDownClock.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import expect from 'expect';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import CountDownClock from 'CountDownClock';

describe('CountDownClock', () => {
    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(CountDownClock).toExist();
    });
});
```

I tried to npm install, it did not help.  I found couple other links mentioned in github but they recommended running npm install and it still kept giving me the same error.  Some help would be appreciated or if you can send me down the correct path to figuring this out.

Comment: Have you run `npm install`?

Comment: @falsarella already ran npm install as mentioned in my question

Comment: Hmmm It was mocha that didnt find expect. That's weird, but try cd node_modules/mocha and then npm install. Go back to the root folder, and retry npm test

Comment: @falserella went into node_modules/mocha and ran npm install and still did not fix it - shows up same error message

Comment: Try deleting node_modules, and npm install again

Comment: @falsarella did that as well this morning and still having issues, same error

Comment: Lol, dont know. File an issue on their github